Does jq map function change the input object?
The docs certainly make it sound like it does not.  But, I can't think of any way to explain the behavior below.  What am I doing wrong?
On some cluster data, I am trying to show the total number of cpus being used out of the total available. I want to iterate through the array of objects in o.json and compute the difference between two values (.cpus.total - .cpus.allocated) and display the sum of those deltas as well as the sum of one of the values (.cpus.total).
So .[].cpus.total will spit out a list of integers:
$ cat /tmp/o.json | jq -c '[.[].cpus.total]|add'
2764

But when I do the same thing after a map statement, it errors:
$ cat /tmp/o.json | jq -c '[(map(.cpus.total - .cpus.allocated) | add), "/", [.[].cpus.total]|add]'
jq: error (at <stdin>:13762): Cannot iterate over number (2556)

That error makes it sound like "add" wanted an array but didn't get one. And sure enough, forcing it into an array (and then taking the zero'th value, because it is just an integer) works:
$ cat /tmp/o.json | jq -c '[(map(.cpus.total - .cpus.allocated) | add), "/", [[.[].cpus.total]|add][0] ]'
[2556,"/",2764]

At this point I have working code but I don't understand why I needed that extra set of square brackets to get it to go, but only if there is a map earlier in the program. What gives?

The final add in your filter is applied not only to the last of the preceding filters but to all three of them (to (map(.cpus.total - .cpus.allocated) | add), "/", and [.[].cpus.total]). Just wrap the last one into parens including add (just like you did in the first one) to have it applied only to that: [(map(.cpus.total - .cpus.allocated) | add), "/", ([.[].cpus.total]|add)]. Also note that map(…) is just a shortcut to [.[] | …], so [.[].cpus.total] and map(.cpus.total) will do the same thing.

Ah, so add is what is being squirrely, not map.  Thank you!


Does jq map function change the input object?

No.  In fact, values are never changed.  jq is a purely functional language, though its scoping rules might make it seem otherwise to anyone not familiar with them.
When we write expressions like {} | .x = 1 | .x = 2 it might look as though the input object is being modified, and inserting debug statements will show that the value associated with "x" changes from null to 1 and then 2. So consider:
jq -nc '{}
 | . as $zero
 | .x = 1 | . as $one
 | .x = 2 | . as $two 
 | ($zero, $one, $two)'
{}
{"x":1}
{"x":2}

